# Android Flip digit anmation for timer

Tags: android, animation, flipclock

Can someone help me to make animation like following in Android for timer ?

https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/FlipClock

Any help appreciated.

Comment: check out https://github.com/anugotta/FlipTimerView

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Vinayrraj/Android-FlipDigitView or https://github.com/vorlovsky/flipper-android can be used.
Also TextSwitcher is an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following Android library:
https://github.com/Fjessin2/flipperclock